# Относительно сложный SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Всем доброго дня. Есть таблицы:
user, order, product, order_product.

Нужно вытащить из таблицы user поле infо. На входе имеем id продукта. По этому айди из таблицы order-product вытаскиваем заказы, из таблицы заказов вытаскиваем уже пользователей, и из таблицы пользователей уже тащим нужное нам поле info.

Помогите составить запрос, пожалуйста!

Comment: Можете показать, какой запрос у вас получился и что именно не выходит. Также добавьте схему базы, без неё сложно что то понять.

Comment: Если честно, совсем позабыл SQL, не могу даже вспомнить как сделать такой запрос.

таблица user: user_id, info.
таблица order: order_id, user_id (FK)
таблица product: product_id, name.
таблица order_product: id, order_id(FK), product_id(FK)

Comment: То есть на входе имею только id товара. Нужно узнать информацию о пользователях (из поля info), которые этот товар заказали.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно попробовать так:

```
SELECT info
FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM order_product AS op
    INNER JOIN order AS op ON (op.order_id = o.order)
    WHERE op.product_id = 1
) AS x ON (x.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую как вариант

Comment: Да, тоже работает)

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался сам) Прошу прощения. Если интересно то:

```
select info from user
where user_id in 
(select user_id as usr from order where order_id in 
    (select order_id as ord from order_product where product_id=1))
```